# Keeping ImportData results in one single cell

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using import data function:

```
=IMPORTDATA("http://www.csl.com.br")
```

However, the results come in a lot of cells. I have a list of websites to do that, so I would need it to come in one single cell. Is there a way to retrieve all of that in one single cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(CHAR(10),SPLIT(IMPORTDATA("http://www.csl.com.br")&CHAR(10),CHAR(10))))
```

[image: 6]

## or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(JOIN(CHAR(10),SPLIT(IMPORTDATA("http://www.csl.com.br")&
 CHAR(10),CHAR(10))),CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),""))
```

[image: 9]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to player0 I got the solution I couldn't find.

```
=join(",",importdata(url))
```

The text I was receiving was similar to

```
{"code":200,text:"{\"Tag\":\"Blablah\"}"}
```

And importdata was occupying 2 cells with it (separating by the ","). I just wanted the content on the 2nd cell but I couldn't parse it because it was already on a different cell (apparently).

Now the whole response gets contained in one cell and I can parse at will.